# Display offer price before normal price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having some trouble with displaying my discount price before the normal price, as you can see [here](http://poster.weshape.dk/?product=ekspression).

I know that I have to use filters, but I don't really know how.

**Here's an image of what I want:**
[image: What I want]

Comment: there's no offer price there... it's the normal price and the discounted price...

Comment: I meant the discount price - But you can see on the image what I want.